# Web development with Apache_MySQL_HTML_Java

Tags: java, javascript, html, mysql, apache

I have some question about how to connect databases with web application use java and html. Sorry if some have mistake to describe. I have some databases and i must to build web application put my databases inside there. SO is it possibly do that or not? If yes from what i must to start? I know java, mysql, html and not so much JavaScript.
Can anyone help me. Thanks for all advance.
When i run php file on netbeans, i got error like:

**Not Found**
The requested URL /SiteTest/index.php was not found on this server.
*Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80*

Thanks for all advance!!

Comment: When i run html file on oracle server the come error: **/home/nasimjon/NetBeansProjects/Test/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1033: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)**

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be learning about JavaScript as web apps tend to use this heavily. AngularJS is the new cool thing.

You will want a Java web app framework. Spring is very popular.

There is a lot of learn, but your existing knowledge of Java, MySQL and HTML will help you.

Comment: Can you recommend on Linux platform?

Comment: Everything I've mentioned works great on Linux, as well as Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can connect to database:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

Connection conn = null;
Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
connectionProps.put("user", this.userName);
connectionProps.put("password", this.password);

if (this.dbms.equals("mysql")) {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
               "jdbc:" + this.dbms + "://" +
               this.serverName +
               ":" + this.portNumber + "/",
               connectionProps);
} else if (this.dbms.equals("derby")) {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
               "jdbc:" + this.dbms + ":" +
               this.dbName +
               ";create=true",
               connectionProps);
}
System.out.println("Connected to database");
return conn;
}
```

more is here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html , you can also search some tutorial on youtube, just type: java datebase connection. Hibernate framework helps you. You should know also JPA/JDBC.

Comment: Thanks, but i have alerady connect mysql in java. I wanna to shown on web browser. With html java or maybe php.

Comment: Aha, OK, super, so now you need a frontend of your application, you can yuse for example Spring MVC + Wicket framework.